# Chrome extension webrequest api not intercepting mailto or any other non http urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Chrome extension webrequest api not intercepting mailto or any other non http urls. Is it possible with webrequest api?

Comment: No, webRequest [can't do that](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: If those links are inside a web page you can listen to `click` or `mousedown` event in your content script.

Comment: ok. If it is on address bar?

Comment: Is there any way to intercept not http urls in address bar?

Comment: There shouldn't be any way for an extension to intercept that since those URLs are handled by external programs. You can try writing a separate utility that uses a low-level system hook for whatever mechanism Chrome is using to launch such URLs, and this utility then would communicate with your extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).